# After clicking a button view is updating on both items of recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with post cards. So there is a like button in every post card. When I tap on a like button. Sometimes it works fine and updates on current item. But after some scroll when I tap on like button it updates on another item simultaneously.

It doesn't send that data to server. But, only the view is updated. Then when I scroll up and down again. The data goes back to normal.

Problem is in the following onClick method:-

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("like").exists()){

                    holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_500_36dp);
                    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("like").removeValue();

                        }
                    });

                }else if(dataSnapshot.child("dislike").exists()) {

                    holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.brokenheart);
                    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("dislike").removeValue();

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_500_36dp);
                    holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("dislike").removeValue();
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("like").setValue(true);

                        }
                    });


                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        holder.like.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("like").removeValue();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("topics").child("likes").child(data.getId()).child(username).child("dislike").setValue(true);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Full Adapter class https://pastebin.com/UnFGahWT

Comment: Issue could be in adapter class.

Comment: I think the problem might exist in a ViewHolder or a Adapter that you might be using. After all, this is just part of the code.

Comment: This is the adapter class. But wait I will upload complete class

Comment: Please check I have added the link in question @TharakaDevinda

Comment: Added the link in question @Yupi

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following:-**

Set Your on click listeners in the  `public ViewHolder(View itemView)` method and make Your ViewHolder class implement the  View.OnClickListener.

*In Adapter add:*

```
  public Topic getItem(int position) {
    return topics.get(position);
   }
```

*In ViewHolder's onClick method add:*

```
 int position = getAdapterPosition();
 if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;
 item = getItem(position);
```

Thus You will get the exact object You need to change or do something with it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - could not get the answer look properly

Comment: I implemented OnClickListener to ViewHolder class and added the operations. But my onclicklistenet function is not getting called. Here is the new adapter https://pastebin.com/jRA8mxCv

Comment: For debug purposes, try to comment out all clicklisteners in the adapter and add a clicklisteners in viewholder costructor at line 177 in Your code: pic.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: I'm getting the same problem adding onClickListener in viewholder. I dont think it's the problem with onClickListeners. Because they just add the value to firebase database and dont do anything to views. So probably something is wrong with the Firebase ValueEventListsener..

Comment: I think it is somehow connected to view recycling - like listener that remains attached to view, even after the view's contents have been changed...

Comment: i tried using boolean conditions in onClickListeners and changed the valueeventlistener to singlevalueventlistener. Then it worked. So it was problem in firebase listener